# regular expression to exclude a specific string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am currently implementing an identity management solution that will provide users the ability to manage all of their endpoint accounts.

Currently, our company password policy matches the default Windows requirements: must contain either a number or a special character, among others.

Unfortunately, in the new system's password policy, we can require a number, a special, or both, but not "one of either." However, the new system allows validation by regular expression.

Currently, we have this set to DISALLOW the following regex:

```
.*[pP][aA4][sS$]{2}[wW][oO0][rR][dD].*
```

This works pretty well. However, we would like to change this to ALLOW either a digit or a special, while also DISALLOWING the previous. Here is what I have tried:

```
((?=.*\d.*)|(?=.*[-'"!#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]\^_`{|}~\\].*))(?!.*[pP][aA4][sS$]{2}[wW][oO0][rR][dD].*)
```

However, I can't get this to work. The digit/special group works fine, however the word group does not. It does see if "password" or some variation is used at the END of the string, but not at the beginning...

Any suggestions? The system uses standard (Perl-style) regular expressions.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly, you must use a number or a special character but you aren't allowed to use a number and a special character?

Comment: You must use either a number or a special character, but you can use both if you like. That part of the regex is working fine. I am specifically looking for an answer about excluding the "password" bit.

Comment: can you test against 2 different regexes sequentially ? first you'd test for the permissibility in general terms. the second regex would match forbidden patterns - if it does, you reject.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean by "one of either". The user must have a number or a special and can use both. But surely that means they can use "one of either" a number or a special?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some trickery it is possible to combine your regexes.

```
^([^pP\d!\-'"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]\^_`{|}~\\]|[pP](?![aA4][sS$]{2}[wW][oO0][rR][dD]))*(\d|[-'"!#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]\^_`{|}~\\])([^pP\d!\-'"#$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]\^_`{|}~\\]|[pP](?![aA4][sS$]{2}[wW][oO0][rR][dD]))*$
```

I've succesfully tested this in the Sublime text editor.

Comment: Thanks mrhobo; I ended up passing this task off to a contractor, but I have tested your solution and it does seem to work fine. I'm going to mark this as the accepted solution. :)

Comment: Should've passed it off to me then :)